# How does SQL Server 2016 round - and how does it compare to other versions?

Tags: sql-server

If I have a decimal value in code which has more than 5 decimal places, and I store the value to a temp table which has a column defined as `Numeric(18,5)`, what does SQL Server do with the value passed in?

Does it round to 5DP, and if so which type or rounding is used?

Or

Does it simply truncate the value passed in to 5DP?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it depends on what your data type is going in to the new object. If yours is a decimal and going to a numeric (18,5) then it should round.
See chart in the *Truncating and rounding results* section [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#implicit-conversions). Thanks to @Paul White on that.

Sample code to verify:

```
/* Load a table with a decimal value with higher precision */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Pre 
CREATE TABLE #Pre 
(
ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
DecVal DEC (18,6) NOT NULL 
) 

GO

INSERT INTO #Pre (DecVal) 
SELECT CAST(RAND() AS NUMERIC(18,6))
GO 100



/* Now load a table with a lower precision, and then join back on the ID to see the results */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Final 
CREATE TABLE #Final 
(
ID INT NOT NULL,
DecVal NUMERIC (18,5) NOT NULL
) 

GO

INSERT INTO #Final (ID, DecVal) 
SELECT
ID,
DecVal
FROM 
#Pre

GO

/* Values follow rounding rules */
SELECT 
F.ID,
F.DecVal AS FinalDec,
P.DecVal

FROM 
#Final F
INNER JOIN #Pre P
ON F.ID = P.ID
```